# Simple python algorithm not behaving as expected

Tags: python

I have a really simple algorithm that's meant to sort some 48 numbers into buckets with specific ranges. For example, if my ranges are `[0, 16), [16, 32), [32, 48)` I would have 3 buckets with 16 integers each.

```
ds = range(0, 48)
bounds = [[0, 16], [16, 32], [32, 48]]
acd = [[]] * len(bounds)

for d in ds:
    for i in range(0, len(bounds)):
        if bounds[i][0] <= d < bounds[i][1]:
            print("Adding %s to %s" % (d, i))
            acd[i] += [d]
```

The print statement works as expected, for example it will print "Adding 47 to 2"

However, the array `acd` which is supposed to contain the buckets, has all 48 elements in all 3 buckets. I'm kind of lost as to why this could be happening since it's such a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
acd = [[]] * len(bounds)
```

`acd` will contain `len(bounds)` times the same empty list.
You need them to be different lists.

```
acd = [[] for _ in range(len(bounds))]
```

The `[x] * n` shortcut is suitable only when you want multiple copies of the same `x`.

Comment: Never would have guessed, thank you! Will accept when it lets me

Comment: "The [x] * n shortcut is suitable only when x is immutable." eh, or when you want to repeat the same object multiple times. Consider the classic "grouper" recipe: `zip(*[iter(some_iterable)]*n)`. So, like a mutable default argument, there is nothing *inherently wrong* with it if you understand the semantics (and as long as you are willing to agree there is nothing inherently wrong with mutable objects)

Comment: @Carpetfizz note, it's quite consistent with the concatenation operator: `+`, so `L = [x]; L + L + L == L*3 == [x, x, x]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point, I was a bit lazy on the wording, kind of counting on other users to call me out on it with something better, so thanks, improved!